# How to uninstall software that is running when the mac logs in

Tags: macos, launchd

I get this every time I log in

[image]

Which is an application that I downloaded a while back. But I can't locate it in my applications folder and I also cant see it in this:

[image]

How should I go about preventing this?

---

## In /Library/LaunchDaemons:

[image]

---

## In /Library/LaunchAgents:

[image]

Comment: Which Application?

Comment: Sorry I am also un shore of that!

Comment: is there anything in `System Preferences > Users & Groups > *your user* > Login Items` that it could be?

Comment: Use **Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app** to list running applications; this will include those that are hidden from your Force Quit list. Knowing the name of the application will help get you a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Activity Monitor first to see if the App is running.
( Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app )

If you can/can not find it there, it may be a launchd-process that has some special name.

Open Finder and hit CMD+SHIFT+G. Check these Folders:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Delete the file you are looking for (App-Name / Company)
but be careful - do not delete any random file.

Restart your Mac.
If it still popp up, it is hidden somewhere else.
I don't know what you installed, maybe it needed admin priviliges and is therefore located in the System/Library/LaunchDaemons folder.

Other Folders that may contain your app/script.

```
/Library/StartupItems
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
```

You could also check the logs via the Console Application.

Comment: Thank you it was some type of keylogger... Naughty I know.

Comment: see update in question

Comment: none of these seem strange to me?

Comment: indeed, maybe in the /Library/StartupItems.
Also check the console for log output at boot.

Comment: You may also want to check `~/Library/LaunchAgents`